# What iOS framework contains CGImageRelease?

Tags: ios

What iOS framework contains CGImageRelease?

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) says it is in ApplicationFramework, but I thought that was an OSX framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in QuartzCore. `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` Was just about to ask when I figured it out.